# Return authorization header to QGIS?

Tags: python, request, python-requests, qgis, wms

I am creating a WMS API that can work with QGIS. I want to be able to provide an extra authorisation layer between QGIS and GeoServer (where my data is stored) within the Flask API that I am building.

What I need from QGIS is a basic Authorization header that I can read and validate against my own database.

I am under the idea that QGIS will send one WMS request without any authorization headers first, then should try again with the basic authorization. My issue is that I don't know how to return to QGIS that authorization headers are required so it can send another request.

My API works when there is no authorization and can pass and return data from QGIS to Geoserver and GeoServer back to QGIS. But I want to use the basic authorization to secure it an extra step.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def get(self):
    print(request.args)
    print(request.headers)

    if 'Auth' not in str(request.headers):
        url = '<amazonDB>/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities'
        res = requests.get(url)
        return Response(res, mimetype='text/xml')

    url = '<amazonDB>/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities'
    res = requests.get(url, auth=('<username>', '<password>'))
    return Response(res, mimetype='text/xml')
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with Apache and added in
WSGIPassAuthorization On

into the config file.